# Kong -- How do I write my entity_checks for array #6989

Tags: lua, kong

#### Summary

I am developing my own rate-limiting plugins based on the official one.

The origin schema looks like:

```
fields = {
    { config = {
        type = "record",
        fields = {
          { second = { type = "number", gt = 0 }, },
          { minute = { type = "number", gt = 0 }, },
        }
...
      },
    },
```

My schema looks like:

```
    { config = {
        type = "record",
        fields = {
          { plans = {
            type = "array",
            elements = {
              type = "record",
              fields = {
                { second = { type = "number", gt = 0 }, },
                { minute = { type = "number", gt = 0 }, },
              }
            },
          },},
        },
        custom_validator = validate_periods_order,
      },
    },
```

You can see that the first field is called "plans" and it's type is an array which means I will have `config.plans[0].second`, `config.plans[0].second`, ... and the original one was `config.second`

Below is the origin `entity_checks` function of rate-limiting, I have no idea how to re-write it to match my schema since it changed from simple `record` type to `array` type

```
entity_checks = {
    { at_least_one_of = { "config.second", "config.minute", "config.hour", "config.day", "config.month", "config.year" } },
    { conditional = {
      if_field = "config.policy", if_match = { eq = "config.redis" },
      then_field = "config.redis_host", then_match = { required = true },
    } },
    { conditional = {
      if_field = "config.policy", if_match = { eq = "config.redis" },
      then_field = "config.redis_port", then_match = { required = true },
    } },
    { conditional = {
      if_field = "config.policy", if_match = { eq = "config.redis" },
      then_field = "config.redis_timeout", then_match = { required = true },
    } },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a local schema for `plan`

```lua
local plan_schema = {
  type = "record",
  fields = {
    { second = { type = "number", gt = 0 }, }, 
    { minute = { type = "number", gt = 0 }, }, 
  },
  custom_validator = validate_periods_order,
  entity_checks = {
    { at_least_one_of = { "second", "minute" } },
  }
}
```

Then on your config set `plans` as an array of `plan`

```lua
return {
  name = plugin_name,
  fields = {
    { consumer = typedefs.no_consumer },
    { protocols = typedefs.protocols_http },
    { config = {
      type = "record",
      fields = {
        { plans = {
          type = "array",
          elements =  plan_schema ,
        } },
    } },
  },
}
```